# Find at least 4 non-digits in a sequence

Tags: c#, regex

I have a sequence for example "123a*a712", which is valid.
I want to ensure that there are only 3 characters which are NOT digits, because 4+ will make it not valid.

Few examples:

"56 + 33" - valid (white space is also a character)

"56 + 33 + 6" - invalid (more than 3 non-digit chars)

"Error" - invalid

"1234" - valid

Thank you!

Comment: Show us what you have done/tried so far. This is no 'let someone else do your work' service

Comment: use this regex "(([0-9]*\D\D\D[0-9]+))*" to compate

Comment: @CSharpie I've had different smaller tries and when I've decided to turn here it was already after different changes, so apologies for not posting the attempts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is no need to use RegEx

```
bool IsValid = "123a*a712".Count(x => !char.IsDigit(x)) < 4;
```

Answer (score 3):

If you absolutely need a regex solution you could go with

```
^(\d*[^\d]?){0,3}\d*$
```

It'll match up to three non-digits.

[See it here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/kL1gK2/1).

Comment: Works just as great, but I personally prefer the LINQ approach that @fubo posted, thanks for answering!

Answer (score 1):

> I want to ensure that there are only 3 characters which are NOT
>   digits, because 4+ will make it not valid.

```
public static int countNonDigit(string str) {
  return (str.Length - str.Count(char.isDigit))
}

if (countNonDigit(str) >= 4) {
  // not valid
}
```

**EDIT**

just realized, the same can be accomplished with `str.Count(!char.isDigit);`

Answer (score 0):

Use an helper:

```
public static class String
{
    public static bool containsAtLeastXNonDigit(string s, int nbOfDigit)
    {
        return s.Count(!char.IsDigit) >= nbOfDigit;
    }
}
```

and use it: `String.containsAtLeastXNonDigit("ToTest", 4);`